# Apply padding in shadow

Tags: html, css

Here I have two buttons first one have full shadow no padding in shadow.

And in second one I put one `<hr>` tag to make shadow with padding.

How can I make shadow like a second button, without any `<hr>` tag.

```css
.boxed {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #000;
}
.round-corner {
  border-radius: 28px !important;
}
.padding-20{
  padding: 0 20px !important;
}
.fixed-in-top{
  margin-top: -1px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary round-corner col-sm-12 boxed" value="Submit and Print">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary round-corner col-sm-12" value="Submit and Print">
    <div class="col-sm-12 padding-20"><hr class="boxed fixed-in-top" /></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you able to use a `<button>Submit and Print</button>` element instead of `<input type="button" value="Submit and Print">`?

Comment: Yes sure, I can use

Comment: Then you can use ::before on your button element with the css you have in hr so you can get rid of hr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "spread radius", the 4th number in the [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) specification, which, when negative, shrinks the shadow.

```css
.boxed {
  box-shadow: 0 20px 5px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.round-corner {
  border-radius: 28px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary round-corner col-sm-12 boxed" value="Submit and Print">
  </div>
</div>
```

I leave as an exercise to you to play with the values to match exactly your other shadow, but this is the way to go.

Comment: @Rishi it wasn't present in your original example, but you can see how to use it in the link on my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `pseudo` element.

```css
.boxed {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
}
.round-corner {
  border-radius: 28px !important;
}
.padding-20{
  padding: 0 20px !important;
}
button.boxed:after {
    content: '';
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px red;
    height: 1px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary round-corner col-sm-12 boxed">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, pseudos can be adjusted for even more configurable shadows!